# Table cell with vertical text direction in HTML to .DOCX with docx4j

Tags: html, css, docx4j, direction, vertical-text

I'm trying to convert an html table with text in vertical direction to docx with docx4j. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Platilla HTML para convertirlo a DOCX</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:11pt;
        }
        .titulo {
            text-align:center;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .contenido {
            text-align:justify;
        }
        .tabla {
            width:100%;
            border:1px solid black;
            border-spacing:0px;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .tabla td, .tabla th {
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        .tabla th {
            background-color: #898989;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: bottom;
            height: 150px;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }
        .verticalText {
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 20px;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            padding-left: 3px;
            padding-right: 3px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);                 
        };  
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tabla">
        <tr>
            <th><div class="verticalText">No. de Item</div></th>
            <th>Departamento / Municipio</th>
            <th>Tipo de Servicio</th>
            <th>Contratista</th>
            <th>Monto maximo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I'm using styles to transform the text to vertical direction...

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

... but when I export from html to docx with docxj4 (in the variable "xhtml" is all the html code to export)...

```
private WordprocessingMLPackage export(String xhtml) {

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = null;
    try {
        RFonts arialRFonts = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createRFonts();
        arialRFonts.setAscii("Arial");
        arialRFonts.setHAnsi("Arial");
        XHTMLImporterImpl.addFontMapping("Arial", arialRFonts);

        wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(PageSizePaper.LETTER, false);
        XHTMLImporter importer = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
        List<Object> content = importer.convert(xhtml, null);
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(content);
    } catch (Docx4JException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReporteContratoEspecialista.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return wordMLPackage;
}
```

.. saving the document...

```
wordMLPackage.save(servletOutputStream);
```

... the cell text is in normal direction, horizontal, in the .docx document.

Is there another way to do that using html to generate docx document?
I need the text vertical in docx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to enhance the [source code](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/) to add that feature.

Comment: So, actually doesn't support text direction from HTML?