# How to tilt table header text in docx4j?

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

I've tried couple of alternative to tilt table header text by 90 degree, but docx4j doesn't support it.

Had tried by adding below property in style attribute. but text getting display default horizontally.

```
mso-rotate:90;
```

&

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126992/table-cell-with-vertical-text-direction-in-html-to-docx-with-docx4j) answer, & came to know docx4j doesn't support this feature. Is there any alternative? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course you can rotate text in a docx file using docx4j.  But are you talking about preserving rotated text when you import XHTML?  If so, you might say that explicitly in your question.

Comment: I'm trying to convert .html to .docx file, where html contains table and its header <td> has CSS property  'transform: rotate(-90deg);' Apart from this property all CSS getting applied in generated document.


Could please let me know the possible alternative to fix this?

Comment: First thing to do is to check whether css transform rotate is supported by Flying Saucer/xhtmlrenderer and passed through to docx4j.  If so, then it ought to be fairly straightforward to add support for it to https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML